# How do I add a user as a field in Drupal 7?

Tags: entities

[References](http://drupal.org/project/references) claims that it is now deprecated in favor of [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference).  But I can't quite connect the dots on how an Entity Reference can point to a specific user.  Ideally, I would have this field simply be the user that originally submitted the node.

Basically, all I want is a "File" content type that includes the user who uploaded the file.  I feel like I am over-complicating it.  Please help.

Comment: If you make a content type the authoring information would be the user who uploaded the file, right? I'm not sure why you'd need to make it an entity reference.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

1. Add a field to the File content type.  For FIELD TYPE choose "Entity Reference".
2. Save and configure the new field.  For Target type choose "User".